# Removing window border?

Tags: winapi, getwindowlong, setwindowlong

I have a window with a solid border around it. How can I remove the border (all of the non-client area) by using **SetWindowLong** and **GetWindowLong**?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In C/C++

```
LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
```

WS_CAPTION is defined as  (WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME). You can get away with removing just these two styles, since the minimize maximize and sytem menu will disappear when the caption disappears, but it's best to remove them as well.

It's also best to remove the extended border styles.

```
LONG lExStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
lExStyle &= ~(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_STATICEDGE);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle);
```

And finally, to get your window to redraw with the changed styles, you can use SetWindowPos.

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
```

Comment: @NathanGoings Can you please explain why this is outdated in your opinion and what is up to date instead?

Comment: @RamboNo5: SetWindowLong() has been superseded by the SetWindowLongPtr function()

Comment: @dns I see, thanks. But as long as you're targeting 32-bit Windows only, it's all the same.

Comment: As a remark, using WS_MAXIMIZE and WS_MINIMIZE seems to glitch the window under Windows 10 setting its state as Minimized/Maximized. 
You should replace these with WS_MAXIMIZEBOX and WS_MINIMIZEBOX to avoid this problem

Comment: `WS_MAXIMIZE` and `WS_MINIMIZE` affect the window's initial state.

Comment: Any ideas on how to restore the borders?

Answer (score 11):

The following Delphi codes does it:

```
  SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE) and not WS_BORDER and not WS_SIZEBOX and not WS_DLGFRAME );
  SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOP, Left, Top, Width, Height, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

Of course, these API calls look the same in all languages.

Answer (score 8):

This line of code below removes the border of any given window, and remains only its client:

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd /*The handle of the window to remove its borders*/, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
```

You can use `WS_POPUPWINDOW` instead in the third parameter of `SetWindowLong` function.
It also removes the borders of the given window and works too, but the difference is that it also draws **outlined** black rectangle all over the remaining client of the window. The thickness of that outlined rectangle is 1 pixel. `WS_POPUP` doesn't draw that rectangle, actually it doesn't draw anything, just only remove window's borders.

If you are about to return back the borders of the window, before you use that line of code I posted above, call first that line of code below:

```
GetWindowLong(hWnd /*The handle of the window that you want to remove its borders and later return them back to it*/, GWL_STYLE);
```

but of course that this function retuns the styles of the window, so create new variable that will keep these styles, i.e. set this variable to the return value of that function.

Then you use `SetWindowLong` as I showen above to remove its borders, and when you want later to restore its borders back, just recall again `SetWindowLong`, the first two parameters are same (hWnd and GWL_STYLE), but the third parameter is the styles of the window that returned from `GetWindowLong`. If you don't want to call `GetWindowLong`, but still return the borders of the window, then you can use `SetWindowLong` with the same first two parameters, and in the third parameter, you can use one of the following: `WS_OVERLAPPED` or/and `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` or/and `WS_SIZEFRAME`.

**NOTE:** If you try my answer, but it doesn't work for you, this can be, because that the both functions `SetWindowLong` and `GetWindowLong` have been superseded and doesn't work for you, and that because they are compatible with **only** **32-bit** version of Windows. Probably you are using **64-bit** version of Windows, then use `SetWindowLongPtr` and `GetWindowLongPtr` instead, which are compatible with **both** *32-bit* and **64-bit** versions of Windows. MSDN informs that about these functions in the **Note** section. Just search for them in that site. Here are the links to them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope that all this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for reminding to use `WS_POPUP`, it is single method working with creating already borderless windows.

Answer (score 1):

This removes the title bar, and the vertical scroll bars...

```
int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    // remove title bar
    LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU);
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
    //remove vertical scrollbar
    ShowScrollBar(hwnd, SB_VERT, FALSE);

    cout << "Hello World! \n";
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to remove the border, but keep the title bar ?

Comment: just use ShowScrollBar(hwnd, SB_VERT, FALSE);