# How using pinvoke to force change border style to none of window?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, border

Is it possible to change border style of window to have no border, using pinvoke?
If it isn't possible, how can i get the client rectangle without borders?
I am standing over problem where each computer opens this window with another param size.

I have specific window with its intPtr hwnd.

Comment: Client rectangle is obtained with `GetClientRect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SetWindowLong` winapi function to set window style. Just use only necessary styles that do not include `WS_THICKFRAME` or `WS_BORDER` or similar

[SetWindowLong](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowlong) and [List of windows styles](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/Window%20styles.html)

Here is the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398746/removing-window-border)