# winapi: removing decoration

Tags: c++, winapi, setwindowlong, getwindowlong

This looks like a duplicate but hear me first. This is more on the debugging side.
I'm trying to remove the borders of my window using the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398746/removing-window-border/2400467#2400467).

What are some things that will make these functions not work? Hiding windows using `ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE)` doesn't work also. I've made my own Window class with many functions so I don't wanna paste my whole code here.

Here's my Initialization function for the window:

```
HRESULT SampleWindow::InitializeSimple(SampleWindow* win)
{
    HRESULT         hr;
    HWND            hWnd;
    SampleWindow*   sampleWin;

    sampleWin = new SampleWindow();

    aMWindowProps->Center();
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        aMWindowProps->aWindowClass,
        aMWindowProps->aWindowTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        aMWindowProps->aRealLeft,
        aMWindowProps->aRealTop,
        aMWindowProps->GetRelativePosWidth(),
        aMWindowProps->GetRelativePosHeight(),
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        *aMWindowProps->aHInstance,
        sampleWin);

    aMWindowProps->aHwnd = &hWnd;

    hr = hWnd ? S_OK : E_FAIL;

    win->aHwnd = &hWnd;
    //ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    return hr;
}
```

`WindowProps` as you can see contains various info about the window being created.
I also have a `HWND` pointer variable in my class which points to the window handler.

Here are some things I've tried on my main, where sw2 is a pointer to my window class:

```
    ShowWindow(*sw2->aHwnd, SW_SHOW);
    //ShowWindow(*sw2->aHwnd, nCmdShow);
    LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(*sw2->aHwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    lStyle &= WS_POPUP;
    //lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU);
    SetWindowLong(*sw2->aHwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
    //ShowWindow(*sw2->aHwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
    //ShowWindow(*sw2->aHwnd, SW_HIDE);
    //ShowWindow(*sw2->aHwnd, SW_HIDE);
    //SetWindowLong(*sw2->aHwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(*sw2->aHwnd, GWL_STYLE) && ~ WS_BORDER && ~ WS_SIZEBOX && ~ WS_DLGFRAME);
    SetWindowPos(*sw2->aHwnd, HWND_TOP, sw2->aMWindowProps->aRealLeft, sw2->aMWindowProps->aRealTop, sw2->aMWindowProps->aRealWidth, sw2->aMWindowProps->aRealHeight, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    //LONG lExStyle = GetWindowLong(*sw2->aHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    //lExStyle &= ~(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_STATICEDGE);
    //SetWindowLong(*sw2->aHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle);
    //SetWindowPos(*sw2->aHwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
```

I'd just like some suggestions on where to debug my code. I know the functions work as I've tested it on a much simpler window project (sample project from Microsoft).

Comment: Are you sure you want the parent window to be `HWND_DESKTOP`?  I'd try without that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Changed that line to NULL but didn't work.

Comment: Your `InitializeSample()` function is fundamentally flawed, you are returning a pointer to a variable on the stack (`hWnd`) which will probably be no longer valid once your function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonathan Potter already pointed out in his comment, your mistake is:

```
aMWindowProps->aHwnd = &hWnd;

hr = hWnd ? S_OK : E_FAIL;

win->aHwnd = &hWnd;
```

where HWND hWnd is only valid in the scope of the current methode. I guess that you defined aHwnd in your class as something like:

HWND *aHwnd;

which is at least unnecessary. You seem to mistake a HANDLE (a HWND is nothing else) as a kind of instance/object itself. It isn't, it is more like a pointer or reference. You can always safely write:

```
HWND myAttribute=hWnd;
```

As long as you use it in the same process. (Window handles are even valid across process boundaries, but do not tell anyone about that).

I fact I know no situation where you keep a pointer to a handle instead of the handle itself.

Notice, I explicit wrote about handles, as HWND are a kind of standard window handles.

Comment: Thank you. I was messing around with pointers to get a mastery of it. This mistake is a one step forward. How would you recommend handling HINSTANCE? As you can see I have a pointer to the original also. Should I treat this the same as a HANDLE?

Comment: @user2280704 yes. A HINSTANCE is also a kind of HANDLE.