# Can't hide (minimize) window after setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

Tags: qt

Operation System is Windows 7.
I use method for my window to produce a borderless window:

setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

Without this flags I may click on application icon on windows control panel and my window would appears, then hides (minimizes) and etc.

But after usage this flag I can't hide my window by clicking on application icon on Control Panel. How may I combine flags to window hides again?

Comment: According to the last comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19717413/344347), adding `Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint` flag should help.